# Passagem de parâmetro usando o " String[] args" declarado na main

Tags: java, arquivo

Estive procurando na documentação da Oracle, exemplos de cópias de arquivos, com seus atributos de diversas formas... Dentro dessa pesquisa me deparei com uma coisa estranha que foi a passagem de parâmetro que estava sendo feita, que era a variável "args" declarada como string na main

Segue o código para mostrar... Gostaria de saber o que está acontecendo e por que foi usado.

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Sample code that copies files in a similar manner to the cp(1) program.
 */

public class Copy {

/**
 * Returns {@code true} if okay to overwrite a  file ("cp -i")
 */
static boolean okayToOverwrite(Path file) {
    String answer = System.console().readLine("overwrite %s (yes/no)? ", file);
    return (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
}

/**
 * Copy source file to target location. If {@code prompt} is true then
 * prompt user to overwrite target if it exists. The {@code preserve}
 * parameter determines if file attributes should be copied/preserved.
 */
static void copyFile(Path source, Path target, boolean prompt, boolean preserve) {
    CopyOption[] options = (preserve) ?
        new CopyOption[] { COPY_ATTRIBUTES, REPLACE_EXISTING } :
        new CopyOption[] { REPLACE_EXISTING };
    if (!prompt || Files.notExists(target) || okayToOverwrite(target)) {
        try {
            Files.copy(source, target, options);
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.format("Unable to copy: %s: %s%n", source, x);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * A {@code FileVisitor} that copies a file-tree ("cp -r")
 */
static class TreeCopier implements FileVisitor<Path> {
    private final Path source;
    private final Path target;
    private final boolean prompt;
    private final boolean preserve;

    TreeCopier(Path source, Path target, boolean prompt, boolean preserve) {
        this.source = source;
        this.target = target;
        this.prompt = prompt;
        this.preserve = preserve;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
        // before visiting entries in a directory we copy the directory
        // (okay if directory already exists).
        CopyOption[] options = (preserve) ?
            new CopyOption[] { COPY_ATTRIBUTES } : new CopyOption[0];

        Path newdir = target.resolve(source.relativize(dir));
        try {
            Files.copy(dir, newdir, options);
        } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException x) {
            // ignore
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.format("Unable to create: %s: %s%n", newdir, x);
            return SKIP_SUBTREE;
        }
        return CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
        copyFile(file, target.resolve(source.relativize(file)),
                 prompt, preserve);
        return CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) {
        // fix up modification time of directory when done
        if (exc == null && preserve) {
            Path newdir = target.resolve(source.relativize(dir));
            try {
                FileTime time = Files.getLastModifiedTime(dir);
                Files.setLastModifiedTime(newdir, time);
            } catch (IOException x) {
                System.err.format("Unable to copy all attributes to: %s: %s%n", newdir, x);
            }
        }
        return CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) {
        if (exc instanceof FileSystemLoopException) {
            System.err.println("cycle detected: " + file);
        } else {
            System.err.format("Unable to copy: %s: %s%n", file, exc);
        }
        return CONTINUE;
    }
}

static void usage() {
    System.err.println("java Copy [-ip] source... target");
    System.err.println("java Copy -r [-ip] source-dir... target");
    System.exit(-1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    boolean recursive = false;
    boolean prompt = false;
    boolean preserve = false;

    // process options
    int argi = 0;
    while (argi < args.length) {
        String arg = args[argi];
        if (!arg.startsWith("-"))
            break;
        if (arg.length() < 2)
            usage();
        for (int i=1; i<arg.length(); i++) {
            char c = arg.charAt(i);
            switch (c) {
                case 'r' : recursive = true; break;
                case 'i' : prompt = true; break;
                case 'p' : preserve = true; break;
                default : usage();
            }
        }
        argi++;
    }

    // remaining arguments are the source files(s) and the target location
    int remaining = args.length - argi;
    if (remaining < 2)
        usage();
    Path[] source = new Path[remaining-1];
    int i=0;
    while (remaining > 1) {
        source[i++] = Paths.get(args[argi++]);
        remaining--;
    }
    Path target = Paths.get(args[argi]);

    // check if target is a directory
    boolean isDir = Files.isDirectory(target);

    // copy each source file/directory to target
    for (i=0; i<source.length; i++) {
        Path dest = (isDir) ? target.resolve(source[i].getFileName()) : target;

        if (recursive) {
            // follow links when copying files
            EnumSet<FileVisitOption> opts = EnumSet.of(FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS);
            TreeCopier tc = new TreeCopier(source[i], dest, prompt, preserve);
            Files.walkFileTree(source[i], opts, Integer.MAX_VALUE, tc);
        } else {
            // not recursive so source must not be a directory
            if (Files.isDirectory(source[i])) {
                System.err.format("%s: is a directory%n", source[i]);
                continue;
            }
            copyFile(source[i], dest, prompt, preserve);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Se notarem no trecho abaixo mostra a passagem, que estou falando, como é a primeira vez que vejo isso, gostaria de uma ajuda pra entender.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    boolean recursive = false;
    boolean prompt = false;
    boolean preserve = false;

    // process options
    int argi = 0;
    while (argi < args.length) {
        String arg = args[argi];
        if (!arg.startsWith("-"))
            break;
        if (arg.length() < 2)
            usage();
        for (int i=1; i<arg.length(); i++) {
            char c = arg.charAt(i);
            switch (c) {
                case 'r' : recursive = true; break;
                case 'i' : prompt = true; break;
                case 'p' : preserve = true; break;
                default : usage();
            }
        }
        argi++;
    }
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma detalhe, `String[]` não é `String`, este simbolo `[]` significa que isto é uma "array" do tipo string. Ou seja ele carrega consigo um ou strings.

Por exemplo este código:

```
public class Exemplo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (String s: args) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Se você chama-lo assim:

> java Exemplo Foo Bar Ola Mundo

Ele irá retornar isto:

> Foo
>
> Bar
>
> Ola
>
> Mundo

Pois a cada espaço ele adicionou um item na "array", ou seja:

- `String a = "ola mundo";` é uma `String`.
- `String a[] = {"ola", "mundo"};` é um vetor de string, ou seja neste exemplo são dois arrays em um vetor.

Note que também existem arrays com outros tipos, como `int[]` que é um vetor (array) de números inteiros.

Veja que na [documentação do java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) tem este trecho:

> When an application is launched, the runtime system passes the command-line arguments to the application's main method via an *array* of *String*s
>
> Quando uma aplicação é executada, o sistema em tempo de execução passa os argumentos da linha de comando para o método `main` usando um `array` de `String`s.

Comment: É esqueci de mencionar que se trata de um vetor de String não de apenas uma... Porém como se trata de um exemplo de cópia de arquivos e diretórios, foi aqui que veio a dúvida da comparação com o vetor de Strings ?

Comment: Então, é uma dúvida... Onde quero chegar é. Se este código faria a cópia de um determinado diretórios, subdiretórios e arquivos o que foi passado como parâmetro fica impossível de compilar... Tentei executar aqui e ele sempre cai no 
metodo static void usage() {
    System.err.println("java Copy [-ip] source... target");
    System.err.println("java Copy -r [-ip] source-dir... target");
    System.exit(-1);
} 

Mas não pega nem um diretório pra copiar...

Comment: @Valdecir Como você passou os argumentos? Vejo que a sua duvida não é sobre `string` ou `string[]`, por favor se puder editar a pergunta e explicar nela isto que acabou de me dizer pra deixar ela mais clara :) vou tentar compilar aqui.

Comment: @Valdecir Como você executou o java? `java Exemplo -r ...`?

Comment: OK... é que este exemplo é do javadoc, vai me ajudar muito entender o que se passa em cada método.

Vou editar aqui

Answer (score 0):

Bom pessoal encontrei a resposta para essa pergunta... Na verdade esse vetor de String declarado na main quando passado como parâmetro, o "valor" tem que estar pré determinado antes da execução do programa, como se fosse apenas um .jar e seria compilado por linha de comando, então os parâmetro tem que ser apresentados junto com a execuão. Para conseguir usar no NetBeans eu segui os passos abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após clicar em Personalizar...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Passei os parâmetros necessários pra meu programa funcionar.

OBS: Aumentei a memória do java para que fique um pouco mais rápida a cópia dos arquivos, e com isso ele copiou 26.2GB em 15 minutos 30 segundos.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Desculpe Valdecir, mas você realmente era o único que poderia encontrar a resposta, já que isto não é mencionado na pergunta, em nenhum momento na pergunta seria possível entender que o problema era com o copiar dos arquivos, recomendo que leia este link:  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Acredito que não... A verdade era que eu precisava de ajuda para fazer este código funcionar, e não estava entendendo o por que estava sendo passado o parâmetro "Caminho/Origem de cópia"... Como pode notar a cópia de arquivos já estava pronta apenas precisava executar o código.

Comment: Então amigo, foi justamente o que eu disse, você escreveu a "pergunta" de uma maneira que só você mesmo poderia responder, não de proposito, mas quem tenta lhe ajuda ao ler a sua pergunta fica sem entender ou entende outra coisa.