# Porque na hora de executar o código ele dá esse erro? java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, exceção, estrutura-de-dados, stack

```
package PilhaEstatica;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numero = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        Pilha p = new Pilha();
        int resto;
        while (numero != 0) {
            resto = numero % 2 ; // pego o resto da divisão por 2 (é 0 ou 1)
            p.push(resto);       // armazeno na pilha
            numero = numero / 2 ;// gero um novo número, resultado da divisão dele por 2
        }

        // fase 2 = exibição de restos
        while (!p.isEmpty()) {
            resto = p.pop();    // remove da pilha o que está no topo
            System.out.println(resto);

        }
        System.out.println("Fim do Programa de Pilha!");

    }

}
package PilhaEstatica;

public class Pilha {
    private int valores[];
    private int topo;


    public Pilha() {
        this.valores = new int[10];
        topo = -1;
    }
    public void push(int elemento) {
        topo = topo + 1;
        valores[topo] = elemento;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return( topo == -1);
    }
    public boolean isFull() {
        return (topo == 9);
    }

    public int pop() {
        int elem = valores[topo];
        topo = topo - 1;
        return elem;
    }
}
```

Comment: linha 7 dá esse erro: int numero = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException por causa do ParseInt?

Comment: É por causa do `args[0]`. Se vc executa o programa sem passar nenhum parâmetro, `args` é vazio, então `args[0]` não existe e por isso dá o erro de index out of bounds

Comment: Hum, só que por exemplo eu passei '10' como parâmetro, e deu erro do mesmo jeito. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at PilhaEstatica.App.main(App.java:7)

Comment: Não é isso. Vc tem que passar parâmetros para o seu programa: https://stackoverflow.com/q/890966

Comment: Hum entendi mais ou menos, desculpe não manjo muito de inglês! Teria como me dar um exemplo de passagem de parâmetro para o programa?

Comment: Gostaria de passar o número 172 como parâmetro, qual seria a forma que você recomenda?

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88350/112052

Comment: Poderia enviar um exemplo direcionado a pilha do meu código? no exemplo diz: "Pois a cada espaço ele adicionou um item na "array", ou seja:

String a = "ola mundo"; é uma String.
String a[] = {"ola", "mundo"}; é um vetor de string, ou seja neste exemplo são dois arrays em um vetor.
Note que também existem arrays com outros tipos, como int[] que é um vetor (array) de números inteiros." no meu caso ficaria como?

Comment: Esse código que estou tendo esse problema foi feito através do de um editor de texto, e compilado direto na máquina virtual do Java por uma janela de comando cmd. Por isso a dúvida, porque estou usando o Spring.

Comment: Quando vc roda no cmd, provavelmente vc digita algo como `java App`. Se vc passar parâmetros, por ex: `java App 172`, aí o "172" estará em `args[0]`. Se vc só roda `java App`, o array `args` é vazio e dá o erro de out of bounds. Veja outro exemplo: https://www.guj.com.br/t/como-executar-aplicacao-passando-parametros/43269/2

Comment: Então no exemplo foi passado assim : int codigo = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);                                    no meu código fiz isso: int numero = Integer.parseInt(args[172]); e mesmo assim estorou a exceção no meu spring. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 172
 at PilhaEstatica.App.main(App.java:8)

Comment: Não é isso. Leia novamente [esse link](https://www.guj.com.br/t/como-executar-aplicacao-passando-parametros/43269/2). Quando vc executa na linha de comando, por exemplo, `java App algumacoisa` o texto "algumacoisa" é um parâmetro, e ele é colocado no array `args`. Como só tem um parâmetro, então `args` só tem um elemento, que está na posição zero, então vc acessa como `args[0]` - veja que o número que está entre colhetes é a **posição** do array, não o valor. Então se quer passar 172, execute `java App 172`, e dentro do programa, em `args[0]` estará o `172`

Comment: No caso então, teria que exportar o projeto e executar pelo cmd. Como no exemplo do link: java -jar oJar.jar Marcos 001